# Google maps api v3 infobubble css Firefox

Tags: css, google-maps, firefox

I have an infoBubble with some text and images. The right aligned image (arrow) is pushed down in Firefox (Mac) but not Safari or Opera dependent on the length of the text to the left and above. See the marker over Australia: http://www.hostelbars.com/map_test_v3_3.html

Here's the css:

```
.infowindow {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.infowindow .iwPhoto {
    background-color: #F00;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.infowindow .iwName {
    background-color: #0F3;
    line-height: 33px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 115px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.infowindow .iwCity {
    background-color: #C03;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-left: 115px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.infowindow .iwCity .iwArrow {
    background-color: #0CF;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: right;
}
```

Aside from the images I don't want the div's to have a fixed width. Would appreciate some help.

Brendon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to only happen the *first* time, and for items with city values longer than name values.  This suggests you didn't set `width` and `height` values for your `img` element (`arrow.png`), so the first time it has no idea what size it's going to be, and subsequent times it does.

What you should probably do is change it to a background image, as it's merely an iconified decorative image meaning 'next' or 'more', and thus should be in CSS's realm of *style*, not HTML's realm of *meaning* (where '`img`' lives).  See [this list of image replacement techniques](http://mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/).

Otherwise, you could just apply `img[src$="arrow.png"] { width: 29px; height: 29px; }`, or add `width` and `height` attributes to the `img` element.